# Exception handling of a function in Python

Tags: python, exception

Suppose I have a function definiton:

```
def test():
    print 'hi'
```

I get a TypeError whenever I gives an argument.

Now, I want to put the def statement in try. How do I do this?

Comment: You should really read the beginners docs on python.org!

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the exact code and error message you get. It's hard to see what your problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: -1: no failing code and no error traceback, I vote for closing the question as "not a real question".

Answer (score 5):

```
try: 
    test()
except TypeError:
    print "error"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: def test():
     ...:     print 'hi'
     ...:

In [2]: try:
     ...:     test(1)
     ...: except:
     ...:     print 'exception'
     ...:
exception
```

Here is the relevant section in the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html)

By the way. to fix this error, you should not wrap the function call in a try-except. Instead call it with the right number of arguments!

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the exact code and error message you get. It's hard to see what your problem is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You said

> Now, I want to put the def statement
>   in try. How to do this.

The `def` statement is correct, it is not raising any exceptions. So putting it in a `try` won't do anything.

What raises the exception is the actual call to the function. So that should be put in the `try` instead:

```
try: 
    test()
except TypeError:
    print "error"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to throw the error at call-time, which it sounds like you might want, you could try this aproach:

```
def test(*args):
    if args:
        raise
    print 'hi'
```

This will shift the error from the calling location to the function.  It accepts any number of parameters via the `*args` list.  Not that I know why you'd want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to handle a variable number of arguments in Python is as follows:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    # args will hold the positional arguments
    print args

    # kwargs will hold the named arguments
    print kwargs


# Now, all of these work
foo(1)
foo(1,2)
foo(1,2,third=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is valid:

```
try:
  def test():
    print 'hi'
except:
  print 'error'


test()
```